# How to loop through open browser windows after leaving page object

Tags: loops, object, browser, window, puppeteer

I’m trying to first open multiple browsers, each with one page by re-using a page object.
I then perform some other actions.
How can I then loop through these open browser windows after leaving the current Page object?
I was thinking of having an array of page objects, or pulling some ID for each object and getting back somehow. Thank you

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function run () {
    const url = 'http://www.example.com';
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const defaultContext = await browser.defaultBrowserContext();
    const browserCount = 10;

    for (let i = 0; i < browserCount; i++) {
        const newContext = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
        const page = await newContext.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);

    }
    
//Perform some other tasks

//Now loop back through the 10 open browser pages.
//Go to the first open browser window, pull data from the page
//Go to the next open browser window, pull data from page

}
run();
```

Comment: You have opened 10 pages, but you have not stored them anywhere since you declare and initialize `const page` variable in every iteration of the loop. And so you have nothing to go back to if you lose references to these pages. I recommend using an array.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment section, you don't store these opened pages anywhere, so you can't really go back to any of them.

The loop should look more like this:

```js
let pages = [];
for (let i = 0; i < browserCount; i++) {
    const newContext = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
    pages.push(await newContext.newPage());
    pages[i].goto(url);
}

// now pages.length === 10, so you can work with any of these pages
// e.g. clicking on some element on the second page:
pages[1].click('#loginForm');
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will do this